# how to fix this php error "warning "?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello guys i had this codeigniter code the model is :

```
<?php

 class Product extends CI_Model{
  var $title;
  var $price;
  var $name=" "; 
  public function __construct($title1,$price1,$name1)  
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->title=$title1;
    $this->price=$price1;
    $this->name=$name1;
  }
  function set_Name ($newname)
  {
    $this->name=$newname;
  }
  function get_Nmae()
  {
    return $this->name;
  }
  function set_title($newtitle){
    $this->title=$newtitle;
  }

   function set_price($newprice) {
    $this->price=$newprice;
 }
 function get_productAttribute (){
  $x1=$this->name;
  $x2=$this->title;
  $x3=$this->price;
  $productattribute  = array( "$x1","$x2","$x3" );
  return $productattribute ;

 }
 public function get_data(){
  $query=$this->db->query('SELECT*FROM Saied');
  return $query->row_array();
 }
  public function insert_indb($var){
  if (is_a($var, 'Furniture'))
  {   
$data= array(
    'id1' => '',
    'name1'=> $this->title,
    'title1' => $this->title,
    'price1' => $this->price, 
    'size1' => $this->size,  
    'material1'=>$this->material

    );
  $this->db->insert('Furn',$data);
  return $data;

 }
 elseif (is_a($var, 'CDDVD'))
 {
  $data1= array(
  'id' => '',
  'title'=>$this->title,
  'price'=>$this->price,
  'name'=>$this->name,
  'sizemb'=>$this->sizeinmb."MB",
  'manufacture'=>$this->manufacturer
   );
  return $data1;
 }
 else 
 {
  echo "no spicifed objech";
 }
}
}
 class Furniture extends Product
{
  var $size;
  var $material;
 public function __construct($title1,$price1,$name1,$sizeset,$materialset)
  {
    $this->size=$sizeset;
    $this->material=$materialset;
    parent::__construct($title1,$price1,$name1);
    $this->name1=" ";
  }
 public function setAtribute_Furniture ($size1,$material1)
  {
    $this->size=$size1;
    $this->material=$material1;
  }
}
 class CDDVD extends Product 
{
  var $sizeinmb;
  var $manufacturer;
  public function __construct($title1,$price1,$name1,$sizeinmbset,$manufacturerset)
  {
    $this->sizeinmb=$sizeinmbset;
    $this->manufacturer=$manufacturerset;
    parent::__construct($title1,$price1,$name1);
  }
  public function setAttribute_CDVD ($sizeinmb1,$manufacturer1)
  {
    $this->sizeinmb=$sizeinmb1."MB";
    $this->manufacturer=$manufacturer1;
  }  
}
$chair = new Furniture("ilove","200 euro"," ","200x200 ","wood");

print_r($chair->insert_indb($chair));

?>
```

and the controller for load this model is :

```
 public function __construct()
      {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('product');
      }


      }
```

the thing is every thing working exactly how i want where i insert intodatabase and print the value from the array or array 1 for every class , but the codigniter give me the flowing error/warning : A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Product::__construct(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/system/core/Loader.php on line 353 and defined

Filename: models/Product.php

Line Number: 7

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/application/models/Product.php
Line: 7
Function: _error_handler

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/application/controllers/Pages.php
Line: 80
Function: model

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 2 for Product::__construct(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/system/core/Loader.php on line 353 and defined

Filename: models/Product.php

Line Number: 7

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/application/models/Product.php
Line: 7
Function: _error_handler

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/application/controllers/Pages.php
Line: 80
Function: model

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 3 for Product::__construct(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/system/core/Loader.php on line 353 and defined

Filename: models/Product.php

Line Number: 7

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/application/models/Product.php
Line: 7
Function: _error_handler

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/application/controllers/Pages.php
Line: 80
Function: model

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: title1

Filename: models/Product.php

Line Number: 11

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/application/models/Product.php
Line: 11
Function: _error_handler

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/application/controllers/Pages.php
Line: 80
Function: model

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: price1

Filename: models/Product.php

Line Number: 12

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/application/models/Product.php
Line: 12
Function: _error_handler

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/application/controllers/Pages.php
Line: 80
Function: model

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: name1

Filename: models/Product.php

Line Number: 13

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/application/models/Product.php
Line: 13
Function: _error_handler

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/application/controllers/Pages.php
Line: 80
Function: model

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SandWeb/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

so my question is how could i ignore those warning or maybe i am loading the model in wrong way . ?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are creating the product please? Instead of having var $name can you change that to public $name and public $title and public $price see if that removes some of the warnings

Comment: You are loading the model in right way, but in your constructor you need 3 values that you never send, or you quit it or initialice like ` public function __construct($title1 = NULL,$price1 = NULL,$name1 = NULL)  ` (in this way, you cant use a general value of the variables)

Comment: in the end of the product i define one product as :$chair = new Furniture("ilove","200 euro"," ","200x200 ","wood");

print_r($chair->insert_indb($chair));

Comment: like i guessing i need to define the object $car = new Furniture in the controller . have any body now how to do this ?

Comment: yes, you are sending constructor values in your furniture, but not in your Product Model from you are extending

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because CI model's constructor can't receive parameters.
See source code of CI's Model Loader  which located in `/YourCIAPP/system/Core/Loader.php` a method named `model`

In the bottom of that method you can see CI load model with this code

```
require_once($mod_path.'models/'.$path.$model.'.php');
$this->_ci_models[] = $name;
$CI->$name = new $model();
```

See, `CI` just new model object with no parameters to Model class's constructor.

Comment: ok so , should i make the first class of the model empty constructor and then , make the other class product ,furniture ..... , i guess then it will work because all i required to load the model . in the controller ? !

Comment: @saiedtrifess Yeah,  have a try I think it will work.

Comment: it did not ! any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

There's only two possibilities : the path is wrong, or the permissions are wrong.